# Can I use a lambda expression to accumulate the sum in the variable?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an `Item[] items` which contains some basic stats about itself.

```
public float getAttackDamage() {
    float bonus = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i] != null){
            bonus += items[i].getAttackDamage();
        }
    }
    return baseAttackDamage + attackDamageScaling * level + bonus;
}
```

The above code is how I currently loop through my characters items and apply their `getAttackDamage()` to the return result.

Is there a way I can rewrite this to use a lambda expressions instead? I tried the follow:

```
public float getAttackDamage() {
    float bonus = 0;
    Arrays.stream(items).forEach(i -> bonus += i.getAttackDamage());
    return baseAttackDamage + attackDamageScaling * level + bonus;
}
```

But it didn't work (compiler error).
Is this possible?

Comment: That compiles here... are you using java 8?

Comment: @luanjot No it does not compile, `bonus` is not effectively final.

Comment: OK, sorry, I had to modify those bits. Just checked that the lambda bit was right. I am sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you could have the following:

```
double bonus = Arrays.stream(items)
                     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                     .mapToDouble(Item::getAttackDamage)
                     .sum();
```

You should remember that `forEach` is probably not the method you want to call. It breaks functional programming (refer to [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845589/can-i-use-a-lambda-expression-here/33845633#comment55456583_33845633)'s comment). In this code, a Stream of each of your item is created. The non-null elements are filtered and mapped to a double value corresponding to the attack damage.

Comment: Yes, that works great. Thanks! Is there any reason when using eclipse if I Ctrl + Space after `Item::` I don't see a list of an auto completion options? It's kind of weird.

Comment: @ShaunWild It depends on a lot of factors (it there's another compilation error or not, if you're a lambda or not...). But yeah, Eclipse auto-completion could be a little bit improved in this area. This is however very difficult to do in practice.

Comment: @Tunaki Pedagogical tip: "breaks functional programming" is not a compelling explanation to those who are not already bought into the benefits of functional programming (and those who have, don't need to be told.)  The real reason is: imperative accumulation is less composible, less maintainable (because side effects are happening deep in the middle of a computation, who knows where), and not parallelizable.  Reduction addresses all these things, and *that's* why its preferable.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thanks a lot, this is indeed clearly better said! :)

Comment: @Tunaki A masterful exploration of the evils of the accumulator pattern: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Thinking-Parallel-Programming